# How to deal with sudden removal of usb volumes?

Tags: python, usb, raspberry-pi, dbus

I'm trying to make my first Raspberry Pi to run a script that uses files from memory cards. Since my Pi does not have a display I want to write it in a fail safe way where it does not matter if somebody pulls the card at any time. Now I'm just wondering what the best way would be. I'm talking about multiple adds and removes of usb sticks per run. The card will be read only.

How would you solve that?
Would you stick to fstab or rather use python to auto mount after detection over dbus?
What kind of clean up is necessary after a volume has been pulled out of the usb slot?

Comment: wouldn't http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/ be better suited for this

Answer (score 0):

Jason, if you use a automount, and define a short commit time on automount configuration, the removal of flash card is secure.
I use "usbmount" service.
My especific config (at /etc/usbmount/usbmount.conf) is:

```
FS_MOUNTOPTIONS="-fstype=vfat,umask=000,commit=1 -fstype=ext4,commit=1,relatime"
```

with define a time of 1 second to start to write on flash card.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. Do I have to do some clean up after the device was pulled or will that be done automatically?

Comment: Excuse-me, JasonTS, only now I read your ask... After 1 second, any data will be write automatically, and can be pulled after the activity light indicator is stopped.